# Nautilus (?) strange look

Tags: nautilus, appearance

I am new to Ubuntu.

My problem is the strange appearance of Nautilus (or Unity?)

[image]

Maybe I have messed up with the tweak tool, so I have deleted the tweak tool and its preferences.

Also tried to reset nautilus and unity to default settings. Didn't help.

How can I repair?

Comment: You are right: that isn't the default look of Nautilus

Comment: what tweak tool did you use?

Comment: unity tweak tool, - https://launchpad.net/unity-tweak-tool

Comment: To me there is nothing awfully wrong... what exactly is it you feel is not right?

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: what's your nautilus version? what's the output of `apt policy nautilus`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue caused by incompatibility of the default Ambiance theme with the Nautilus version.

GNOME developers love to break this and that between GTK releases. Since Ubuntu 16.04 is shipped with mostly GTK 3.18 components including nautilus, updating the nautilus and GTK with break the compatibility of those applications with default Ambiance theme.

You need to downgrade to default nautilus and GTK. I think you've added gnome3-staging PPA.

So, remove it with this command

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
```

If you prefer to stay with GTK 3.20 in 16.04, You have to find themes that work well with GTK-3.20.

The list of themes that supports GNOME 3.20 is few. Here is a list

- Arc theme. Use their github page https://github.com/horst3180/arc-theme or Noobslab PPA https://launchpad.net/~noobslab/+archive/ubuntu/themes
- Numix theme. Use the above PPA

**If you want to use default Ambiance theme:**

If you really want to use the Ambiance and Radiance theme, you can download the light-themes package from Yakkety release and install it in 16.04. It works fine in my test.

- Download it from here http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/all/light-themes/download
- Install it using following command while you're on the directory of the downloaded deb file.

  ```
   sudo dpkg -i light-themes*.deb
  ```

Comment: This helped, thank you very much! What can i do for you?)

Comment: @rainbow Glad that this helped. You've accepted the answer. That worked as thanks :)

Comment: @rainbow May I ask what exactly helped? Did you purge the repository? or installed the theme from Yakkety?

Comment: When i tried to purge the repository in terminal, it didn't work, there was some kind of a mistake. But i removed it in the software center. It didn't change the situation, so i installed the Ambiance theme and everything was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

To get started, press `Ctrl+Alt+T` to open a terminal window. When it opens, run the below command to reset Unity and Compiz settings:

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

After that, run the below command to restart Unity:

```
setsid unity
```

Comment: Ok, nothing changed.

Comment: reboot the computer

Comment: Nothing changed.